# Check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh for Apollo not working?

Tags: xcode, graphql, apollo, run-script

I am trying to install Apollo in my iOS Project. I follow the instructions here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation.html. When I complete the "Adding a Code Generation Build Step," I get an error. It cannot find the file check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh. The error is "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code." So I checked the file path it was giving me. It seems that "check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh" doesn't exist, but "check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh" does. So I changed the last line of the script in my project to check-and-run-apollo-codegen.sh. However, it still does not work ("Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" again). What do I need to do?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error here on Apollo 0.20.0 using `Cocoapods`

So I use the script provided by Apollo [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation/#adding-build-step)

And customized to my workspace

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Apollo/scripts/run-bundled-codegen.sh" codegen:generate --target=swift --includes=./**/*.graphql --localSchemaFile="schema.json" API.swift
```

Worked for me =D